# Visual Studio 2010 professional responds very slowly when

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

For me Visual Studio 2010 professional responds very slowly  when I use it for WPF developement. It does not happen as soon as I open the solution, but after i continuously use for some time with WPF related activities like coding, debugging, switching between different wpf views etc. After some time everything get slow like ctl+ tab, right click, typing everything...

Btw my system is of decent configuration.
quad processor with 4 GB of RAM

Any idea why it happens or if anybody else facing same problem?

Comment: The WPF designer in VS is like this, I'm afraid.  Slow to start with and gets slower and slower with use.

Comment: Likewise, I never use the WPF designer, but I find VS2010 runs like a dog sometimes. ctrl tab is often unresponsive and ofter stops working. Changing a namespace the project properties can take up to five minutes, with the cpu hovering around 25%. It's OK for small projects but it really struggles with large applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designer is a little slow and various plugins to VS2010 can also slow down performance. 
however, one thing to note is that VS2010 actually runs your code when you open the designer. i had a project where the developers added a bunch of threading and logic to the forms that ended up geting run by the designer, causing poor design time performance.

VS does have some ways of preventing this from happening, for example, the normal constructor is not run at the design time, but some things will run such as variable instanciations for example.

What you can do is launch another VS instance and attatch the debugger (Debug > attatch to process) to the first VS instance. you can then break the execution of the first instance and see if any of your code is beeing run by the designer.

Comment: It's a good point that your own code can cause terrible trouble to the designer - I have seen custom WPF controls bring VS2010 completely to its knees through excessively (absurdly) expensive layout recalcs.

Comment: Good Point. I shall try that. one qn: what do you mean by " you can then break the execution of the first instance and see if any of your code is beeing run by the designer"

Comment: you'd have your main VS instance, `main`, then you'd start another one `debug`. once `debug` is attatched to `main`, you select debug>break all in `debug` to halt `main`. then you can go into the threads view (debug > windows > threads) and see if any threads are in your code. you can also set breakpoints in your code and see if `debug` hits them

Answer (score 2):

It may be unrelated, but check for two things:
1 - Disable hardware acceleration. I had an horrible time with visual studio, not being able to type and all, until I disabled it.
2 - If you happen to have unwanted VirtualBox/VMWare plugins, they may be hogging up everything.

Comment: Disabled Harware Acceleration. I shall observe if it improves the behaviour of VS

Comment: Ah, relief.. performance is definately improved. still under observation. :)